# Want to talk about some strange effects of "mean crease"

Tags: modeling

Mean crease is one of the best things I love about blender, and I totally think it should be the standard for all subdivision modifier solutions. But here is a strange effect I noticed about mean crease:
  I was trying to model a handle on a drawer, at first it was fine, but when I decided to change the shape of the handle and it became:

[image]

To demonstrate this effect better, here is a example:

[image]

Mean crease of 0 and 1 work as expected, any number in between became buggy.

Can someone tell me whats cause this problem or if I'm using mean crease wrong.
Also the shading with the mean crease in the gif is strange, I know blender view-port shading is not accurate but this also shown in the rendering.

Comment: For what you are trying to do in the animated gif. My personal step is to use bevel edge for the adjacent edge between the 2 Creases. That is to say apply a bevel to the vertical edge and use the 2 edges to control the corner's curve if you need it to be absolutely straight.

Comment: Yes,some cases with mean crease problems i just add geometry instead of adds mean crease to inbetwwen edges,but I do hope to use mean crease to its best.